# Dialog-type notebook

Tags: gui-construction, interface, interactive, dialog-window

I have the following dialog to calculate the product of a and b:

`CreateDialog[
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[a], Number, FieldHint -> "enter a"], 
    InputField[Dynamic[b], Number, FieldHint -> "enter b"], 
    Button["run", MessageDialog[ToString[a b]]], 
    Button["Close", DialogReturn[]]}]];`

Upon execution of this cell, it works exactly the way I need, giving this:
[image]

Is there a way that this dialog appears without opening the notebook? I just want to double-click on the notebook file and see the front end and this dialog appearing. Any help appreciated!

Comment: No, I mean .nb.

Comment: you mean save the dialog as a notebook that you subsequently click on and open directly? Try `NotebookSave`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dialogs` are notebooks with different from regular options settings, so you can export save them as you want:

(*that is the case with palettes too*)

```
Export[
 FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "myDialog.nb"}], 
 CreateDialog[ 
  Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[a], Number, FieldHint -> "enter a"],             
    InputField[Dynamic[b], Number, FieldHint -> "enter b"], 
    Button["run", MessageDialog[ToString[a b]]], 
    Button["Close", DialogReturn[]]}]] 
]; 

SystemOpen @ $TemporaryDirectory
```

Comment: perfect... wow! Thanks!